# Is it possible to give a paragraph indentation of previous block?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document that I've styled as follows.

The headings have a level of indentation. Level 1 has no indentation and level 2 and 3 have 0.5 cm and 1 cm.

Then there's style called code, which is used to highlight code fragments.

I'd like code to have the indentation depending on which heading it exists under.

Is this possible in word. Or can a style only have fixed indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure styles have only a fixed indentation.

My usual approach in a situation like this would be to create three styles, "Code 1" through "Code 3", each with the indents defined for the corresponding heading level.

Dynamic indenting based on the heading level would probably require VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it; you can have one style that has different indentation measures because this is the function of `Characters` style type.

**Creating a Character-type Style**

Assuming you already have created some heading styles (e.g. `Heading 1`) with different indentation measures. Create a new style (from the Ribbon \ `Home` tab \ expand `Styles` gallery \ `Create a style`). Expand the dialogue box (using button `Modify`):

- Write in a `Name` (let's call it `CodeBlock`).
- Choose `Character` from the `Style type`. **Note: You won't be able to change this setting later so you have to set it only once in this process**
- Base your style on a style you won't delete later (e.g. `Normal`).
- Change other properties such as font (e.g. `Courier New`) and shade (button `Format` > `Border` > Tab `Shading` > pick a colour in `Fill`).
- Confirm your changes to return to your document

**Using This Style**

If you are among the people who format while they type, and say you are writing in `Heading 1` style and it's time to write codes in a new line.

- Key in `Enter`.
- Change to style `CodeBlock` (from the `Styles` gallery or by hitting assigned shortcut keys).
- `CodeBlock` style will inherit the paragraph settings of `Heading 1` including the indentation.

If you are among the people who format after finishing with writing everything.

- Highlight the code and the paragraph(s) that precede(s) it.
- Apply `Heading 1` on these paragraphs.
- Highlight only the code.
- Apply `CodeBlock` on the code paragraph.
- `CodeBlock` style will inherit the indentation settings from `Heading 1`.

[image]

**Pros**

- Does what you desired.

**Cons**

- Character-type styles miss many paragraph-specific properties, such as assigning `CodeBlock` for the following paragraph when modifying a style. Obviously this is what distinguishes these styles.

**Extra**

1. For `Heading 1`, modify it to follow itself in the `style for the following paragraph` in the `Modify Style` dialogue box.
2. To assign shortcut keys to style `CodeBlock`, go to `File` \ `Options` \ Tab `Customise Ribbon` \ Button `Keyboard shortcuts: Customise`

   - From menu on left `Categories`, choose `Styles`.
   - From menu on right `Styles`, choose `CodeBlock`.
   - In the space under `Press new shortcut key`, key in you desired keys (e.g. ALT+C,B).
   - Make sure you don't use an existing shortcut keys by noting the `Currently assigned to:` says `[unassigned]`.
   - Click button `Assign`.
   - `Close` and confirm your changes where applicable.